# Computationally intractable orbit of a monoid action on a finite set

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, computational-complexity, semigroups-and-monoids

Suppose for each integer $n\geq 1$ we have a submonoid $M_n\subset \mathrm{Self}(\{1, \dots, n\})$ of self-maps of $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

A *characterization of* $M_n$ is an algorithm that takes an integer $n\geq 1$ and a self-map of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ as input and decides whether the self-map lies in $M_n$.

A *characterization of* $M_n(1)$ is an algorithm that takes two integers $n\geq i\geq 1$ as input and decides whether $i$ lies in $M_n(1)$.

Suppose we have a characterization of $M_n$ that runs in polynomial time in $n$. Is there a characterization of $M_n(1)$ that runs in polynomial time in $n$?

Comment: If the only information you have is such an efficient algorithm checking whether a map lies in $M_n$, it sounds to me that the worst case is basically when $M_n=\{\mathrm{id}\}$ (or is very small), since the procedure seems to basically check all $n^n$ maps until being sure the given element does lie in the orbit of $1$.

Comment: added an assumption

Comment: I see, but what if $M_n$ is the set of all maps fixing $i$? This has size $(n-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than listing the elements. For example suppose your monoid has all self-maps with image {2,...,n} and may or may not have a random map that takes 1 to 1 and {2,...,n} to {2,...,n}, and this map and whether or not it exists is given by inverting a hash which is polynomial time in $|M_n|\cdot n$. Then evidently there is no faster way to determine whether 1 is in your image than inverting the hash.

Comment: question revised

Comment: @DmitryVaintrob Do you have a membership test for your submonoid that runs in polynomial time in $n$?

Comment: It's understandable as you are a new contributor, but you should keep in mind that significantly revising a question multiple times is bad form in mathoverflow, since future readers will not be able to understand old comments/answers. Generally if you find yourself having to revise multiple times that means your question is not ready for mathoverflow, and you need to either figure out what it is you actually want on your own, or find an upstream point of confusion and ask a question about that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would point out however that the requirement for a polynomial time membership test was present in all versions of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** In my previous answer I took $M$ to be the set of elements with image $\{2,\dots, n\}$ together with a random involution. In fact, that answer does not produce a monoid, since the square of an involution is the identity $\text{id}$ which was not an element of the monoid defined.

Here is a correct answer. Take $M\subset \text{Self}(\{1,\dots, n\})$ to be the set consisting of the identity, and the set of elements that have image in $\{\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \dots, n\}$. Let $\sigma$ be a perfect hash on involutions that are the identity on $\lfloor n/2\rfloor, \dots, n$. Let $M_\sigma$ be the monoid consisting of $M$ and the involution $f_\sigma$ with $\sigma(f_\sigma) = 0,$ if it exists. Then you can check that $M$ is always a monoid, but you can't compute $f_\sigma(1),$ and hence the image of $M_\sigma,$ in polynomial time.

**Note** With the current formulation of your question, it is actually enough to take $M$ to be $\text{id}$ and a random involution determined by a perfect hash. In a previous version, you asked that $M$ be enumerable in a length of time which is polynomial in $|M|,$ and adding in all elements with image $\{\lfloor n/2\rfloor,\dots, n\}$ guarantees this.

Comment: Could you expand what these standard cryptographic assumptions are? Do they apply when you are taking the preimage of one element?

Comment: The assumption is that there exists a (in this case, "perfect") hash function which does not have a polynomial-time inverse. This is a standard cryptographic assumption but would fail if, for example, P and NP were equivalent.